# Why I am getting blob length 0 in MediaStream Recording API in mobile chrome browser?

Tags: reactjs, audio, next.js, blob, web-mediarecorder

I am building a simple audio recorder in next js which will send audio blob to server after the recording ends.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const useRecorder = () => {
  const [audioURL, setAudioURL] = useState();
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
  const [recorder, setRecorder] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Lazily obtain recorder first time we're recording.
    if (recorder === null) {
      if (isRecording) {
        requestRecorder().then(setRecorder, console.error);
      }
      return;
    }
    // Manage recorder state.
    if (isRecording) {
      recorder?.start();
    } else {
      recorder?.stop();
    }
    // Obtain the audio when ready.
    const handleData = (e) => {
      setAudioURL({
        data: URL.createObjectURL(e.data),
        type: e,
        name: e.name,
      });
    };
    recorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", handleData);
    return () => recorder.removeEventListener("dataavailable", handleData);
  }, [recorder, isRecording]);
  const startRecording = () => {
    setIsRecording(true);
  };
  const stopRecording = () => {
    setIsRecording(false);
  };

  return [audioURL, isRecording, startRecording, stopRecording];
};
async function requestRecorder() {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
  return new MediaRecorder(stream, { type: "audio/x-mpeg-3" });
}
export default useRecorder;
```

I am using the above hook to start, stop and generating the blob. Everything is working in desktop version but in mobile chrome browser the length of the blob is 0. Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Do you find the solution?